# ITextSharp add annotation with Chinese content

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I add an annotation with Chinese content to PDF using iTextSharp but it cannot display the content in PDF. when I input English content, it can display correctly. Is that possible to embed the font to that annotation? I'm using ITextSharp 5.5.8 and [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5tk7KqtLjSzS1FqN1dQSmRvaXc/view?usp=sharing) is the sample PDF

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {

            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(file);
            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms, '\0', true);

            Rectangle annotRect = new Rectangle(60, 750, 120, 670);

            PdfContentByte canvas = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfContentByte(stamper.Writer);
            canvas.SetColorFill(BaseColor.RED);
            canvas.SetColorStroke(BaseColor.RED);

            BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont("c:\\windows\\fonts\\mingliu.ttc,0", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

            PdfAnnotation annotation = PdfAnnotation.CreateFreeText(stamper.Writer, annotRect, "測試", canvas);

            PdfDate pdfdate = new PdfDate();

            annotation.Flags = PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_READONLY | PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_LOCKED | PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT;

            annotation.Put(PdfName.CREATIONDATE, pdfdate);
            annotation.Put(PdfName.M, pdfdate);
            annotation.Put(PdfName.NM, new PdfString(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));
            annotation.Put(PdfName.RC, new PdfString("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><body xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xmlns:xfa=\"http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/\" xfa:APIVersion=\"Acrobat:11.0.13\" xfa:spec=\"2.0.2\" style=\"font-size:12.0pt;text-align:left;color:#FF0000;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;font-family:'MingLiU';font-stretch:normal\"><p dir=\"ltr\"><span style=\"font-family:MingLiU\">測試</span></p></body>"));

            stamper.AddAnnotation(annotation, 1);

            stamper.Close();
            reader.Close();
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After considering many weird possibilities, the solution turns out to be simple.

The OP sets the richt text content like this:

```
annotation.Put(PdfName.RC, new PdfString("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><body xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xmlns:xfa=\"http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/\" xfa:APIVersion=\"Acrobat:11.0.13\" xfa:spec=\"2.0.2\" style=\"font-size:12.0pt;text-align:left;color:#FF0000;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;font-family:'MingLiU';font-stretch:normal\"><p dir=\"ltr\"><span style=\"font-family:MingLiU\">測試</span></p></body>"));
```

in particular the `PdfString` constructor with only a single `string` argument is used. This constructor is documented (in the corresponding iText Javadocs; the iTextSharp code comments are missing the important detail) as:

```
/**
 * Constructs a <CODE>PdfString</CODE>-object containing a string in the
 * standard encoding <CODE>TEXT_PDFDOCENCODING</CODE>.
 *
 * @param value    the content of the string
 */
public PdfString(String value)
```

The standard encoding `TEXT_PDFDOCENCODING` (PDFDocEncoding) *can encode all of the ISO Latin 1 character set and is documented in Annex D* of the PDF specification [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf).

Clearly Latin-1 is not sufficient to encode Chinese characters. Thus, the alternative encoding UTF-16BE for PDF strings needs to be selected (which *can encode all Unicode characters*). To do so, a different constructor has to be used:

```
/**
 * Constructs a <CODE>PdfString</CODE>-object containing a string in the
 * specified encoding.
 *
 * @param value    the content of the string
 * @param encoding an encoding
 */
public PdfString(String value, String encoding)
```

with the encoding constant `TEXT_UNICODE`:

```
annotation.Put(PdfName.RC, new PdfString("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><body xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xmlns:xfa=\"http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/\" xfa:APIVersion=\"Acrobat:11.0.13\" xfa:spec=\"2.0.2\" style=\"font-size:12.0pt;text-align:left;color:#FF0000;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;font-family:'MingLiU';font-stretch:normal\"><p dir=\"ltr\"><span style=\"font-family:MingLiU\">測試</span></p></body>", PdfObject.TEXT_UNICODE));
```

Now Adobe displays the annotation as desired:

[image: screenshot]